# Use WebSphere MQ as the messaging layer for Springboot applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I need to use WebSphere MQ as the messaging layer for my Springboot apps.

Using RabbitMQ, Kafka or activeMQ is straight forward with Springboot and there are tons of examples available.

There seems to be a dearth of examples using Springboot and WebSphere MQ. I have searched a lot for examples and there are very few examples. I did find a couple of blog posts by Piotr Ciruk in this space. I am trying to use them at the moment.

http://ciruk.pl/2015/04/connecting-to-ibm-mq-with-spring-boot-and-jms/

I would want to stick with the approach of having the compile time dependencies only to generic JARS (i.e JMS and Spring JMS jars) and have the runtime dependency on WebSphere MQ when I run it in my test and prod environments.

Considering that WebSphereMQ has wide-spread presence in a lot of enterprises, I was under the impression that one should be able to get some good examples.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Is your problem still open? Just asking, we implement many integrations with WebSphereMQ.

Comment: @WalterKuhn. Thanks for asking. The problem is no longer open. It has been over 2 or 3 years since I moved out from that engagement.